# When you delete a 'label' from your Google Contacts

Tags: google-contacts

When you delete a label from your google Contacts, (Delete label but keep contact info) where does the contact info reside now?  I assumed it would go to the main Google "contact"  list, but they did not.  Help please.

Answer (score 1):

If they're not in your main "Contacts" list, look in "Other Contacts". (Scroll down the left navbar to near the bottom.)

"Other Contacts" are...

> People you’ve interacted with in Google products, as well as any contacts you’ve hidden from your list. These contacts appear as autocomplete suggestions to help you communicate and share. Go to your Google Account to control how these contacts are saved.